# Embedding a subquery in a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, inner-join

I'm trying to combine these queries by embedding one in the other:

```sql
SELECT Fall.SamplePointID, SoilProperties.pH
FROM
(SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz (Diameter, 0) AS D 
FROM SeedlingStatus 
WHERE Season = "fall") AS Fall INNER JOIN SoilProperties ON Fall.SamplePointID = SoilProperties.SamplePointID;

SELECT Fall.SamplePointID
FROM (SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz (Diameter, 0) AS D 
FROM SeedlingStatus 
WHERE Season = "spring")  AS Spring INNER JOIN (SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz (Diameter, 0) AS D 
FROM SeedlingStatus 
WHERE Season = "fall")  AS Fall ON Spring.SamplePointID = Fall.SamplePointID
WHERE Fall.D> Spring.D;
```

I've tried combining them in ways like this, but then I get an error saying that it cannot find the table "Fall"

```sql
SELECT Fall.SamplePointID, SoilProperties.pH
FROM Fall INNER JOIN SoilProperties ON Fall.SamplePointID = SoilProperties.SamplePointID, (SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz (Diameter, 0) AS D 
FROM SeedlingStatus 
WHERE Season = "spring") AS Spring INNER JOIN (SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz (Diameter, 0) AS D 
FROM SeedlingStatus 
WHERE Season = "fall") AS Fall ON Spring.SamplePointID = Fall.SamplePointID
WHERE Fall.D> Spring.D;
```

Comment: What exactly is your end goal here? Just to have the data sets from these stacked on top of each other? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Use Access query designer. Build innermost query first and save. Build next query that references first query object then copy/paste first query SQL into second. Save that query. Repeat for the next level. When the final query works, can delete the intermediate objects. Show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: Comma in the ON doesn't make sense.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. Please format code reasonably--per syntax & semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the *Fall* derived table is the common data source, simply add *Spring* as a second `INNER JOIN` to first query. Remember too unlike other SQL dialects, MS Access requires parenthesis pairings with more than one join.

```sql
SELECT Fall.SamplePointID, sp.pH 
FROM ((
    SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz(Diameter, 0) AS D 
    FROM SeedlingStatus 
    WHERE Season = 'fall'
) AS Fall 
INNER JOIN SoilProperties sp
    ON Fall.SamplePointID = sp.SamplePointID)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SamplePointID, Season, Nz(Diameter, 0) AS D 
    FROM SeedlingStatus 
    WHERE Season = 'spring'
) AS Spring
    ON Fall.SamplePointID = Spring.SamplePointID
WHERE Fall.D > Spring.D
```

Hopefully, the Microsoft team will upgrade Access' current SQL dialect in future release including adding CTEs per my [feedback ticket](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2b2671a8-b67b-ec11-a81b-000d3a7c83cc)!